# Split string after x amount of same number

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I need to split a string in C# as follows:

The string is something like this: `0000120400567`

There are always `0`s at the beginning. In the example above there are six zeros followed by `120400567`. I want to split the string that I get the last part `120400567`.

The amount of zeros at the beginning might change (the last part number will increase by one number) that means we can have `001245878945` and what I want is `1245878945`.

How can I split this string leaving off the first 0 or the first x amount of zeros and get the end number only? It might be so that the number don't have any zero at the beginning and the number starts directly from the first number ... but it might be that the number contains 8 zeros and than 2 or more number of digits.

Comment: are you trying to `split` a **range of numbers**..in that case it's **ok** to split it with the `regex` as given in the ans but **if** it's going to be a `single number` than using `regex` would be an **overkill** specially if you are going to `split` it with `regex`...

Comment: Why not just parse it to an integer and cast it back to a string?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string withoutLeadingZeroes = withLeadingZeroes.TrimStart('0');
```

(or

```
string withoutLeadingZeroes = Regex.Replace(withLeadingZeroes, "^0*", "");
```

or

```
string withoutLeadingZeroes = new String(
    withLeadingZeroes.SkipWhile(c => c == '0').ToArray());
```

or ...)

Answer (score 9):

`TrimStart` is your friend. However, you need to be careful that you don't end up with an empty string when your original consists of 0s only.

```
string s = "0000120400567";
s = s.TrimStart('0');
if (s == "")
    s = "0";
```

Comment: nitpicking: `if (s.Length == 0)` might be a tad faster

Answer (score 5):

You could use `int.Parse` to convert the String into an Integer. This would drop leading zeros, but is of course limited to strings within the range of int (or long, if you use it).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you convert it into int32 or long or whatever you want and then convert it into a string ?

```
int i = int.Parse("0000120400567");
        string s = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range of numbers in the string you can use `(?:\b(?:0+|(?=[1-9])))` to split that string

So splitting `0534 000500 35435 040` with the above `regex` would end up with

```
534 
500
35435 
40
```

---

If it's going to contain only a single number `Regex` is not required then and especially `splitting` it

But if you still want to `split` that string,you can do it with `(?:^0+|^)`